# Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, option-type

I guess this is basic Swift, so I'm a bit embarrassed to ask:

In my app, I download a plist file from a server as such:

```
 Alamofire.download(url, to: destination).response { response in
       if let url = response.destinationURL {
                    self.holidays = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url)!
                }
            }
```

The file is a valid file, and it is succesfully dowloaded and sitting physically in my Documents folder.

However, the app crashes on

```
self.holidays = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url)!
```

saying

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What gives?

Comment: `NSDictionary(contentsOf: url)` can return `nil` which would trigger that crash. You may want to check the file actually exists first and/or adjust the path if needed.

Comment: Can we assume that you already read [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @Martin yes you can

Comment: Well, then you know the forced unwrapping crashes if `NSDictionary(contentsOf: url)` is nil – did you investigate that possibility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NSDictionary is failing to initialize, so when you try to force unwrap it (with the exclamation mark) it fails and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) {
    self.holidays = dictionary
}
```

Alternatively you can use the guard statement:

```
guard let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) else {
    print("NSDictionary failed to initialise")
    return
}

self.holidays = dictionary
```